# using subquery in order to join columns from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i started learning SQL and there is something i dont understand

i want to take the columns **product_id and product_name** from Production.products
and join it with the **quantity** column from the Production.stocks table
but instead of using join i want to use a subquery.

this is the code i wrote so far: 
and i don't understand why it isn't working :(

```
SELECT P.product_id, P.product_name,(
SELECT S.quantity 
FROM Production.stocks AS S
WHERE S.product_id = P.product_id)
FROM Production.products as P;
```

[image: the database i am working with]

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: instead of getting a table with the three columns i get the error : Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: this query with inner join is more easier than nested query

Comment: Yes i know but i want to practice with nested queries as well, i just dont understand the error i am getting

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, @michox2 . How can a subquery, which is returning a dataset (2+ rows in this case), be displayed as a scalar value? A `JOIN` is what you here. Otherwise we need consumable sample data and expected results.

Comment: I applaud you for wanting to learn. This self imposed requirement is hopefully a learning experience about why we want to use joins instead of a subquery for this type of thing. There are other ways to use a subquery that might help you understand how they work.

Answer (score 1):

did you mean select all data from products table and show quantity column for each product?

```
SELECT P.product_id, P.product_name, isnull(s.quantity, 0) as Quantity 
FROM Production.products as P
left join Production.stocks AS S
    on p.product_id = S.product_id
```

if you have one to many relation with Products and Stocks you should use subquery like this

```
SELECT P.product_id, P.product_name, isnull(s.quantity, 0) as Quantity 
FROM Production.products as P
left join ( 
   select product_id, sum(quantity) as Quantity
   from Production.stocks
   group by product_id)
as S on p.product_id = S.product_id
```

it will be produced aggregated sum value for quantity field

Comment: Yes this is the the final result i want to get but using nested queries instead of joins :)

Comment: @michox2 if this the case, just use outer apply. 


SELECT P.product_id, P.product_name,qty.quantity 
FROM Production.products as P OUTER APPLY (
SELECT S.quantity 
FROM Production.stocks AS S
WHERE S.product_id = P.product_id)qty;

Answer (score 1):

First, let's clear up the fact that it is not recommended to use a subquery at all. Do it only for your own research reasons;  if you have performance or code clarity in mind, go with the simple join.

When you make a subquery on the `SELECT` clause by enclosing it in parenthesis, you are forcing the result to be *one single value*. If not, you get the error you receive.

Usually, subqueries are used in the `FROM` clause, where they should be given a name and then represent a table. Like this:

```
SELECT P.product_id, P.product_name,S.quantity
FROM Production.products as P
inner join 
(
    SELECT quantity 
    FROM Production.stocks 
) as S on S.product_id = P.product_id
```

You can see from the simplicity of the subquery of how little use it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUM keyword for prevent error and give you total quatity.

```
SELECT P.product_id, P.product_name,(
SELECT SUM(S.quantity) 
FROM Production.stocks AS S
WHERE S.product_id = P.product_id)
FROM Production.products as P;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a need at all for a subquery.

If the products are unique entities then surely a join onto the stocks table and doing a sum on the quantity would be more beneficial in terms of query performance

```
SELECT 
    Production.Products.Product_id, 
    Production.Products.product_name,
    SUM(Production.Stocks.quantity) AS Quantity
FROM 
    Production.Products 
LEFT JOIN
    Production.Stocks 
    ON 
        Production.Stocks.product_id = Production.Products.product_id
GROUP BY
    Production.Products.product_id, 
    Production.Products.product_name
```

If you need it to quote stock quantities by store then you need to add an addition join onto stores and add the store to the select and group by clause like so

```
SELECT 
    Production.Products.Product_id, 
    Production.Products.product_name,
    Sales.Stores.store_name,
    SUM(Production.Stocks.quantity) AS Quantity
FROM 
    Production.Products 
LEFT JOIN
    Production.Stocks 
    ON 
        Production.Stocks.product_id = Production.Products.product_id
LEFT JOIN
    Sales.Stores
    ON
        Production.Stocks.store_id = Sales.Stores.store_id
GROUP BY
    Production.Products.product_id, 
    Production.Products.product_name,
    Sales.Stores.store_name
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much :) there really isn't a need for a subquery for this but i saw in a video that someone did it and wanted to play with it in order to see how much i understood

Comment: @michox2 In general avoid sub queries as much as possible as they can become a performance nightmare.